# Simple Real Analysis Problem - Using comparison test to prove a series diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Let $a_n > 0$ and suppose that $\sum a_n$ diverges. Prove that $\sum a_n b_n$ diverges for all sequences $\{b_n\}_n$ with $\liminf_n b_n >0$.

I know this is a simple problem. I already proved using the fact that $a_n b_n$ does not converge to 0 and thus the series must diverge. However, I am not sure how to prove this using the comparison test with $\sum a_n$. We would need to deduce that $a_n < a_nb_n$ but how can we do that? Does $\liminf_n b_n >0$ implies this? What if $b_n=0.01$ for all n?

Comment: Why doesn't $a_nb_n$ converge to $0$?

Comment: @EclipseSun Since ∑  diverges, $a_n$ must diverge or converge to a non-zero number. And since $b_n$>0 for all n, $a_nb_n$ doesn't converge to 0. This was my logic. Do you think this is incorrect?

Comment: Take $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=1$ for an example.

Comment: @EclipseSun True...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If $\liminf b_n = \alpha >0 $  then there exists $N$ such that $ b_n > \alpha/2$ for all $n >N$

Comment: What can you say about $\alpha$? How can we deduce $a_n < a_nb_n$ from this?

Comment: With $a_n>0$, $a_nb_n$ must be greater than a constant $c= \alpha/2$ times $a_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and so $\sum a_n b_n$ diverges by the comparison test since $\sum ca_n$ diverges.

Comment: Can you say the same even when $a_n=1/n$, the harmonic series?

Comment: I just realized it doesn't matter since we are given that $\sum a_n$ diverges

Comment: Yes — $\sum \frac{c}{n} =c\sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty$

Comment: Important property of $\liminf b_n$ is that eventually $b_n > \liminf b_n -\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I used $\epsilon = \alpha/2$ for convenience since the difference must be positive.

Comment: Recall that the comparison test says if $x_n > y_n >0$ eventually  and $\sum y_n$ diverges then $\sum x_n$ diverges

Answer (score 0):

First few terms of a series do not affect convergence or divergence of the series. There exist $b >0$ and $m$ such that $b_n \geq b$ for all $n \geq m$.  Hence $\sum a_nb_n$ is divergent.

Comment: I understand. But what can we know about $b$? How can we tell $a_n < a_nb_n$?